# C# Storing forms in a generic list (Form_load called without calling it)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am not sure on how to explain this issue, but I am saving a couple of forms together with a menu (generic list) and when I first add the forms to the generic list, it calls the form_load (or something, the constructor is getting called) and it "caches" the form.

Example

```
public class Menu
{
 public Form Page {get; set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}

 public Menu(Form p, string n)
 {
  Page = p;
  Name = n;
 }
```

And its being called like this

```
List<Menu> Menu = new List<Menu>();
Menu.Add(new Menu(new Start("Data here"), "Home"));
```

So lets say some values has changed since I first ran the page where I added the values to the list, they gets "cached". So the new changes doesn't apply until I reload the page and adds the new object to the list.

Is this by design or have I missed something and is this poor design?

Sorry for explaining it so poorly, hopefully you'll understand :)

Comment: `Menu.Add(new Start("Data here", "Home"));` should be `Menu.Add(new Start("Data here"), "Home");` and `Start` is a subclass of `Form`?

Comment: Yeah spelling mistake ;) I have a container panel where all the forms in the list gets loaded into when you click it, then it gathers the Form (Page) and loads it into the panel (Not a subclass).

Comment: you shouldn't use parented forms, when the form is added to a panel.  .NET Framework provides UserControls for this purpose...

Comment: Your example and code are more confusing than helpful (and won't compile), can you please share some actual code you have?

Comment: @ShadowWizard , I am not at home right now, but I'll provide more information in a couple of hours (thought maybe I could get a hint by getting you basic info about the problem, but I guess I was wrong ;P

Comment: Not really, I can't understand what you're trying to do so actual example with actual code might help.

Comment: @ShadowWizard , to shorten it down, is it possible to "store" a form in a list without it being called when its added to the generic list. Like when I wan't to call the constructor or form_load when I need it, not upon loading (now All "menu"'s are loaded at the same time and then cached. I wan't it to "reload" and call the form_load (constructor) when I press the menu button. Maybe this is the wrong way togo, that's why I am asking (My english is not the best so my problem might not be explained correctly ;P

Comment: **One advice for you**: When you learn something, you have to **use the concepts and terminologies** specific for it. Don't call it `Page` in `winforms`, just call it `Form`. In `WPF`, you will call it `Window`, in `Java` you call it `JFrame` ... Calling like you do will make you **confused** forever and you won't never be best in the new fields. That's terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Form.Load Event documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the event will be raised

> before a form is displayed for the first time.

In other words: the eventhandler will be called when the form is fully initialized and **not** when you call `Show()`.

You may override the `OnLoad()` method of your form (with an empty body) and - when the time is right - simply call `base.OnLoad()`.
Or you may register an eventhandler for the `Shown` event, which gets called once a form is shown for the first time and update the values which have changed.

For further information on the order of events that will be fired on a windows form, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx).

Comment: Looks promising :) I'll take a look at it when I get back home

Comment: Form_Load() was the key ;)